# php only writing some values into database

Tags: php, javascript, html, ajax, mysqli

I am having an issue with my php not writing the values it is getting from my ajax script into my MySQL database. I know that the php script is getting the values because they are being echoed in my browser. but when i check my database, only two out of the five values are being inputted. I am sure this isn't a nuance, but I can't seem to crack this.

**==============EDIT=============**

The values that aren't being written are first name, last name, and job. ($fname, $lname, and $job respectively)

**==============EDIT=============**

**PHP**

```
<?php

//db connecting variables
  $hostname = "foobase";
  $username = "foobase";
  $dbname = "contactformbase";
  $password = "password";
  $con = new mysqli($hostname, $username, $password, $dbname);
  $tbl_name = "client_base";

//Connecting to your database
  if ($con->connect_error) {
        die('Connect error (' . mysqli_connect_errno() . ')' . mysqli_connect_errno());
    }
    echo 'success!...' . $con->host_info . "\n";
  print_r($_POST);
  $fname = $_POST['fname'];
  $lname = $_POST['lname'];
  $email = $_POST['email'];
  $address = $_POST['address'];
  $job = $_POST['job'];
  $message = $_POST['message'];

//adding values into the database.
  $sql="INSERT INTO $tbl_name (First Name, Last Name, Email, Address, Job)VALUES('POST_['first_name']', '$lname', '$address', '$email')";
  $result = mysqli_query($con, $sql); 
    if($result){
      echo "success";
      }
    else {
      echo "error";
      }
```

**Javascript**

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $("#submit").click(function(e) {
        e.preventDefault();
var data_string = $("form#contact").serializeArray();
alert(data_string);
$.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: "database.php",
    data: data_string,
    success: function(){
        alert(data_string);
    }
});
return false;
</script>
```

**HTML**

```
<form action="" method="POST" id="contact">
    <table>
        <tbody>
            <tr>
                <td><h2>First Name: </h2></td>
                <td><h2>Last Name: </td>
                <td><h2>Email Address: </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td><input type="text" name="first_name" placeholder="Johnny"></td>
                <td><input type="text" name="last_name" placeholder="Appleseed"></td>
                <td><input type="text" name="email" placeholder="johnny@email.com"></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td><h2>Street Address:</h2></td>
                <td><h2>What's Dirty?</h2></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td><input type="text" name="address" placeholder="123 Applegrove Rd. Appletown, VA 12345"></td>
                <td>
                    <select name="job" form="contact">
                        <option value="house">House</option>
                        <option value="roof">Roof</option>
                        <option value="garage-shed">Garage/shed</option>
                        <option value="other">Other</option>
                    </select>
                </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td><h2>Message: </h2></td>
            </tr>
        </tbody>
    </table>
   <textarea name="message">
</form>
```

Comment: Use an `echo $sql;` and you will realize what the error is.

Comment: @hjpotter92 I got back, "[object Object],[object Object],[object Object],[object Object],[object Object],[object Object],[object Object],[object Object]"

Comment: -1 for the phrasing. Strictly speaking, it is your code writing values, not PHP

Comment: Well I'm sorry it wasn't very clear. I have only been getting into PHP /MySQL for the last few weeks. @YourCommonSense

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have the wrong field names in your `PHP`.

Change...

```
$fname = $_POST['fname'];
$lname = $_POST['lname'];
```

to

```
$fname = $_POST['first_name'];
$lname = $_POST['last_name'];
```

Also check the `insert` statement. It has wrong values against the fields - Address for Email, Eamil for Address.

Comment: Fantastic! Thanks! As you probably learned, I am extremely new to php, mysql.

Comment: No worries. Enjoy coding :-)

Answer (score 0):

You are using strange variables `POST_['first_name']`.

Try this query:

(**Note:** you have to use the quotes (`'` `'`) for the fields because you have a space in field names or use PDO to prepare and execute query.)

```
$sql="INSERT INTO $tbl_name (First Name, Last Name, Email, Address, Job)
      VALUES('$fname', '$lname', '$address', '$email')";
```

Other issue is the `POST` array, you send `first_name` instead of `fname` and `last_name` instead of `lname`:

```
<tr>
    <td><input type="text" name="first_name" placeholder="Johnny"></td>
    <td><input type="text" name="last_name" placeholder="Appleseed"></td>
    <td><input type="text" name="email" placeholder="johnny@email.com"></td>
</tr>
```

This will return:

```
$_POST = array(
   "first_name" => "Johnny",
   "last_name" => "Appleseed",
   "email" => "johnny@email.com"
);
```

As you see you don't have `$_POST['fname']` and `$_POST['lname']`
so you have to change:

```
$fname = $_POST['first_name'];
$lname = $_POST['last_name'];
```

About *job*, you just didn't add it in `INSERT` statement:

```
$sql="INSERT INTO $tbl_name (First Name, Last Name, Email, Address, Job)
      VALUES('$fname', '$lname', '$address', '$email', '$job')";
```

Comment: ah, I had forgotten to change that back. However that isn't the issue.

Comment: I am not quite understanding what you mean?

Answer (score 0):

```
$sql="INSERT INTO". $tbl_name ."(First Name, Last Name, Email, Address, Job) VALUES('". $_POST['first_name'] ."', '". $_POST['last_name'] ."', '". $_POST['adress'] ."', '". $_POST['email'] ."')";
```